# Does a laptop preloaded and working properly with Ubuntu imply that installing Debian instead will work just as well?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, debian

I'm looking at a linux laptop (Dell Precision 5550 mobile workstation) and instead of the preloaded Ubuntu 18.04, I would like to install Debian. Here are a few related questions:

1. Since Dell is preloading Ubuntu, does it imply that all hardware is linux-certified
2. Since Ubuntu is based off Debian, does it imply that there would be no issues if one were to install Debian
3. If Debian can be installed with no issues, does it matter which version of Debian? Does it have to be the same version Ubuntu 18.04 is based off of. And, if so, how do I find the compatible Debian version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is **highly likely** that Debian will work fine on it, working on Ubuntu is not a guarantee it will work with Debian.  ( Ubuntu has/had wider hardware support then Debian ).

For most devices, any version of Linux that runs a kernel not older then the one shipped with the device will work, so you are not stuck to a particular Ubuntu version.

Linux does not care about model of computer, it cares about the chipsets the devices use.  A device designed to work with Ubuntu will be designed to have good support for the chipsets that are in use - so whether its Ubuntu or Debian it should make little difference.   Dell tend to run fairly standard chipsets, which makes this easy - and indeed the specs I've found show its Intel all the way which is about as Linux compatible as it gets.

Further comfort can be had that this is certified for Redhat 8.2 - this is good because Redhat has a smaller subset of drivers then Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your informative and optimistic response. In case I try Debian and find out that some particular thing doesn't work, can I easily get back to the Dell preloaded 'state' OR can I simply download Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 latest release version and install it (want to know if the Dell preloaded Ubuntu 18.04 did not come with any special sauce that I will loose if I experiment with Debian)?

Comment: One related question... instead of Debian, if I wanted to try FreeBSD would you say "highly likely FreeBSD will work fine too" OR "an Ubuntu/RedHat certified laptop doesn't mean much to FreeBSD compatibility"?

Comment: @user1284757 Re Ubuntu you can use a standard Ubuntu install, no need fir a Dell one.  Ihave no idea about FreeBSD.

Comment: If I use a Debian Live CD would it boot and everything work EXACTLY like if it was actually installed? Or are there any gotchas / assumptions because of which something might not work when actually installed? Really hoping the behavior is identical so that I can test out without messing with the preloaded Ubuntu. And if this is true for any Live CD, I could test FreeBSD as well without mucking with the installed OS.